# Stream YouTube video in Full HD resolution on iOS Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari, youtube

I have an iPhone X and an iPad Pro, both running iOS 11. I notice, when streaming a YouTube video in iOS Safari, the video resolution is limited to a maximum of 720p.

For e.g., when watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quLUNvBeBtU) video on Safari on macOS, I am able to stream it in the maximum available resolution i.e. 1080p. But in Safari on iOS, the output is limited to a maximum of 720p.

Is this behaviour configurable in YouTube settings or Safari? I notice, the same video can be played back at full resolution in the Videos app in iOS, when downloading it on a Mac and transferring it on iOS device.

I do not wish to use the YouTube app for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Safari on iOS is restricted from playing videos at Full HD resolution. To view them at higher resolution, using the YouTube app is your only resort.

Comment: That's the same answer from the duplicate I posted, too.

Comment: I have marked the question as duplicate too.